# Executing process on cmd, does not process

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am running ffmpeg from Java. Using it to convert flv files to mp3.

When I run the code below, ffmpeg starts, creates a new file (the .mp3 one) but runs at 0% of CPU. When I stop the JAVA app (from netbeans) ffmpeg remains open and goes from 0% to 99% per Windows task manager (CTRL-ALT-DEL). Another weird thing is going on. The output from ffmpeg is not being printed.

The thread is starting but for some reason java is not giving it any time to do its processing.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

```
public class ConverterThread extends Thread {

 String fileToConvert;
 String fileToCreate;
 GetSong getSong;



public ConverterThread(String downloadLocationOnDisk, GetSong getSong) {
   this.fileToConvert = downloadLocationOnDisk;
   this.getSong = getSong;
}


public void run(){
    try {
        Thread cur=Thread.currentThread();
        cur.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

           String downloadLocationOnDisk = fileToConvert;

            if(downloadLocationOnDisk.contains(".flv"))
                fileToCreate = downloadLocationOnDisk.replace(".flv", ".mp3");

            if(downloadLocationOnDisk.contains(".m4a"))
                fileToCreate = downloadLocationOnDisk.replace(".m4a", ".mp3");



            String cmdLine =  "ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i \"" + fileToConvert + "\" \"" + fileToCreate +"\""; 

            System.err.println(cmdLine);

             // run the Unix "ps -ef" command
             // using the Runtime exec method:
             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);


             BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                  InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

             BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                  InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

             String s;

             // read the output from the command
             while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(s);
             }

             // read any errors from the attempted command
             System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
             while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(s);
             }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConverterThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. See here http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=2

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is somewhere here:

```
Thread cur=Thread.currentThread();
cur.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```

Your Java environment has maximal priority and does not give ffmpeg enought CPU time. In fact consider not to use thread priority at all because it can lead to different behaviour in different OS/environment.

Also you are waiting for end of ffmpeg command here:

```
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

So, you will wait here until ffmpeg finish, which is hard if java has all cpu time.

Comment: Can you try to exec something like `gedit` or `notepad.exe`? What result will it produce? I've tried your code and had running `gedit` application. Also I've seen output too.